# Counting and grouping over multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this data from my current query

```
Status Name
1      Lester Boyer
2      Lester Boyer
4      Lester Boyer
1      Lester Boyer
2      Lester Boyer
0      Lester Boyer
3      Lester Boyer
1      Lester Boyer
1      Rosalinda Marks
2      Rosalinda Marks
```

But I would like to count the number of status against that user, so the final table should look like

```
Status Name            Count
0      Lester Boyer    1
1      Lester Boyer    3
2      Lester Boyer    2
3      Lester Boyer    1
4      Lester Boyer    1
1      Rosalinda Marks 1
2      Rosalinda Marks 1
```

Current query is

```
SELECT allocation.status, CONCAT(profile.forename, ' ', profile.surname) AS name
FROM allocation
  INNER JOIN user ON allocation.user_id = user.id
  INNER JOIN profile ON user.id = profile.user_id
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY allocation.status, profile.forename, profile.surname

Comment: No, you also need to select COUNT(*).

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to need the `user` table in your query.  Your version simply needs a `group by`:

```
SELECT a.status, CONCAT(p.forename, ' ', p.surname) AS name, COUNT(*)
FROM allocation a INNER JOIN 
     profile
     ON p.user_id = a.user_id
GROUP BY a.status, CONCAT(p.forename, ' ', p.surname) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT allocation.status, CONCAT(profile.forename, ' ', profile.surname) AS name, COUNT(allocation.status) AS Count
FROM allocation
  INNER JOIN user ON allocation.user_id = user.id
  INNER JOIN profile ON user.id = profile.user_id
GROUP BY CONCAT(profile.forename, ' ', profile.surname),
         allocation.status
ORDER BY name, allocation.status
```

Comment: Not concat/group by safe. User 'Rose O' 'Donnel' will be counted with 'Rose' 'O Donnel'.

Comment: Not sure I got you, can you type your example here please?: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39e5d/1

Comment: If you concat the name before grouping, it's possible that persons with e.g initials may be grouped together. Instead, if you group by forename, surname that won't happen.

Comment: In that case data should be cleaned first. If there would be such first name as 'Rose O', then ok. But there should be a name with first name 'Rosie' and last name 'O''Donnell'.

Comment: @VardanShahinyan . . . There are better examples:  "Rip Van" + "Winkle" and "Rip" + "Van Winkle".  However, that does not seem to be the subject of your question, because you seem happy enough with the results your current query is producing.